# how to solve the problem with put one data in mono to another mono in Spring Webflux?

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I want to get a string data from another server by webclient object, and put it to another Mono object. But in a webclient, only readable that in `.subscribe()`.

Because `responseBody.subscribe()` method is async, method `test()` will be return `result` object with empty `message` field before `responseBody.subscribe()` executed.

Of course, I knew that if I return `responseBody` object instead of `result` object, there is no problem. But I want to return not a `responseBody` object but `result` object with not empty field of `message`.

I want to return result when `responseBody`'s `subscribe()` is completed. 
How to change my code? 
Please help me.

```java
public Mono<ResultVO> test() {
    Mono<ResultVO> result = Mono.just(new ResultVO());

    WebClient client = webClientBuilder.baseUrl("http://XXXXXX").build();
    Mono<String> responseBody = client.get().uri("/aaaa/bbbbb").retrieve().bodyToMono(String.class);

    responseBody.subscribe( s -> {
        result.subscribe(g -> g.setMessage(s));
    });
    return result;
}
...

@Data
public class ResultVO {
    private long timestamp;
    private String ip;
    private String message;
    ...
}
```

I expect like this

```
{
    "timestamp": 1566662695203,
    "ip": "192.168.1.1",
    "message": "c0db76f6-4eb5-4f84-be8d-018d53b453bb"
}
```

But result data is,

```
{
    "timestamp": 1566662695203,
    "ip": "192.168.1.1",
    "message": ""
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Putting this kind of logic into the subscribe method is not recommended, it can easily lead to 'callback hell' and eventually unmaintainable code. Also, I don't see the caller of the shared `test` method, but chances are that one of the Monos is subscribed twice, which also leads to quite confusing behaviour.

Instead, to combine Monos you can use zip, zipWith, flatMap and a couple of other operators.

One solution with zipWith method:

```java
public Mono<ResultVO> test()
{
    WebClient client = WebClient.builder().baseUrl("http://XXXXXX").build();

    // dummy representation of another data source (db query, web service call...) 
    Mono<ResultVO> result = Mono.just(new ResultVO());

    Mono<String> responseBody = client.get().uri("/aaaa/bbbbb").retrieve().bodyToMono(String.class);

    return result.zipWith(responseBody,
            (resultObj, body) -> new ResultVO(resultObj.getTimestamp(), resultObj.getIp(), body));
}
```

Couple of other notes:

- If you are returning JSON through a REST endpoint of your reactive WebFlux application, then you never need to subscribe manually, Spring will do that for you
- Avoid using mutable objects (the ones which you modify after creation with setters), instead create new object, this will make your code easier to reason about and less prone to concurrency issues
- [Useful read about available Reactor operators](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#which-operator)

Comment: this code creates two `ResultVO` which is unnecessary overhead.

Comment: At first it's created by the data source, which is a `Mono.just` I'm assuming for the sake of simplicity. In the second place, a new one is created to support immutability as described in the answer. The performance overhead is insignificant.

Comment: The imutability can be achived by mapping and instead use a builder pattern or a constructor in a mapping statement. Creating 2 objects is ugly, unnessasary memory allocation, and overhead.

Comment: As I've said in my previous comment I'm assuming the first result comes from a different data source (another database, a web service...) and the poster only written a Mono.just for the sake of simplicity. Obviously, in this current form it doesn't make sense to use another Mono, but based on the question I assumed what the poster really wants to achieve.

Comment: Don’t assume things just to be able to write an answer. If you need clarifications you write a comment and ask the poster to clarify. This answer promotes bad practice.

Comment: The question asks how to put a Mono into another one, so I consider it a strong assumption.

Answer (score -2):

First of all, you hardly ever subscribe in your own application.

Think of it this way. Your server is a publisher, that means that your server fetches data and then publishes it to whomever wants it.

The subscriber is usually the end client, that could be a react application, an angular application or any client.

I think you need to read up on the basics of how to use webflux and reactive programming.

This is how to do what you are asking for, with as minimal changes to your code, we `map` what we fetched to what we want returned.

```
public Mono<ResultVO> test() {

    final WebClient client = webClientBuilder
        .baseUrl("http://XXXXXX").build();
    return client.get()
            .uri("/aaaa/bbbbb")
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(String.class)
            .map(message -> {
                    final ResultVO resultVO = new ResultVO();
                    resultVO.setMessage(message);
                    return resultVO;
                }
            );
}
```

Comment: _'First of all, you never subscribe in your own application.'_ - That's not really true. If you develop a process which runs in the background, then it's totally valid (and necessary) to call subscribe. 

When you develop a REST API, where you return reactive types in the controller, then subscribing is not needed, indeed.

Comment: @MartinTarjányi no it might not be true in that 1 case of 1000 but for people starting out its much easier to understand that you never subscribe in your own application. But sure, if you want to nitpick on super minimal details then we can never have any discussion at all.

Comment: If you use a different phrase, like 'almost never', then it's okay. But stating that 'never have to subscribe' is just false information. But I see you've already rephrased it, so never mind.